# D3 V4, How can I have a tick mark at every data point, but a label at only select data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As you can see from the image I'm using monthly data. I'm trying to find a way to display every tick mark, but only the April month labels. example: Apr 2014, Apr 2015, Apr 2016 and Apr 2017 - and keep the tick marks in between.
Thanks in advance.

[X axis generated from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9X2d.png)
[image]

```
   g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
                             .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")  )
                           );

    g.select('.axis.axis--x')
    .selectAll("text") 
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```

Thanks to Sira, this is what I ended up with:

```
 g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
                         .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")  )
                        );

g.select('.axis.axis--x')
.selectAll("text") 
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
                        .style("opacity", function(d){
                                if (d3.select(this).text().includes("Apr")){return "1"}else{return "0"}
                                })             
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```

Comment: Somthing like this? https://bl.ocks.org/erikvullings/41be28677574fd484b43e91413a7e45d

Comment: @ian That's cool, but not quite what I'm asking. Is there no way to isolate specific labels. If label contains "Apr" return opacity 1, else return ""

Comment: I think you meant @RyanMorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`d3.class`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) with callback. Inside the callback, you will have an access to the datum, index and `this` respectively.

So if you want the ticks to only show up if it contains "Apr" in the data, you can do something like:

```
g.select('.axis.axis--x')
.selectAll("text") 
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("display", function(d, i, this) {
               if (!d.contains("Apr") {
                  return "none";
               }
            })
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );
```

You can replace the if with other statements that will return `"none"` for the data point that you want it to disappear.